Minimum cardinality of a set on which a perfect group acts transitively
Let $G$ be a finite or numerable perfect group acting transitively on a set $X$. I need to prove that $|X| \geq 5$. I am also working with the extra hypothesis that for all $x \neq y$ in $X$, there exists $g \in Stab_G(x)$ with $g(y) \neq y$, and I don't know if I should also use this hypothesis to prove the claim.
What I have learnt is that $Alt_5$ is the smallest perfect group and I think that this information could be useful, but I don't understand how to tackle this problem and, in particular, I don't understand why there are no perfect groups with order bigger than $|Alt_5|$, that act transitively on a set of cardinality smaller than 5.
Of course, by the orbit-stabiliser theorem, $|X|=[G:Stab_G(x)]$, but I don't know if this information could be useful.
Any hint is greatly appreciated.

It would be enough to show that every transitive subgroup of $S_n$ for $n\leq 4$ has a nontrivial abelian quotient (why is that enough?). Do you know these subgroups? Also, to avoid trivialities, you probably intend to ask about nontrivial transitive actions as $X={*}$ is always an example.

You need to assume that $|X|>1$, but you don't need your extra hypothesis. As Tim Seifert indicated, the result follows from the fact that $S_n$ is solvable for $n \le 4$.

Many thanks for the answers! I understood how to procede. As @DerekHolt suggests, it is sufficient to note that $S_n$ is solvable for $n \leq 4$… therefore is it superfluous to assume that the action is transitive?

You need to assume that the action is nontrivial.

Yes, of course. Thank you very much!
